# How to detect is opengl ruunning on Desktop or ES

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I'm writing crossplatform library on C++ and OpenGL.
I want to know how to detect whether I running on OpenGL Desktop, or ES?

Maybe sowehow with glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inside Shader:**
According to http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf (page 12) there should be **GL_ES** define. If it is 0, or absent - you using dektop implementation, otherwise - ES.

**In other places:**
**GL_ES_VERSION_2_0** defined here http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/GLES2/gl2.h. So if it defined - we're on ES system.
Wikibooks recommend it, also:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_03

Comment: Is that all you wanted, to know within a GLSL shader if the implementation is GLES or GL? That is a very different question from what you originally wrote.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - "I want to know how to detect whether I running on OpenGL Desktop, or ES?" Is GL_ES not be defined if we are running on OpenGL ES ?

Comment: `GL_ES` will only be defined in a GLSL shader. You still have the issue of determining whether you are running on desktop or ES in your actual application.

Comment: And what about GL_ES_VERSION_2_0? It defined in http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/GLES2/gl2.h. Seems somenone rely on it http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_03

Comment: That could work, but that is more of something that you determine at compile-time rather than run-time. So it depends on why you need to know if it is desktop GL or GL ES. In that example you linked to, it creates a different version of the shader depending on how the software is compiled.

Comment: I need them for the same reason :) I think it is impossible to run GL ES without khronos libraries. So I can't imagine why this can be needed at run-time.

Comment: Well, on AMD hardware AMD offers an implementation of EGL that can run side-by-side with WGL or GLX. Since a great deal of the API between OpenGL ES and OpenGL is functionally identical, it is possible for a toolkit such as Qt (especially), SDL, glfw, etc. to completely hide the underlying implementation. In such a case you might be given GLES or GL and a common subset of functions. So it definitely is possible to leave the decision between GLES or GL until run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing version strings to tell anything about an OpenGL implementation has always been taboo. They are for **human** eyes only, otherwise there would be a stricter set of rules governing how the string had to be formatted and compliance guarantees before a version number could be reported.

---

That said, the GLES specification is stricter than GL on this matter so it could be possible:

#### [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) - 6.1.5 String Queries - pp. 128

> The **`GL_VERSION`** string is laid out as follows:
>
> > "OpenGL ES N.M vendor-specific information"

In OpenGL a compliant implementation will format its `GL_VERSION` string this way:

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20130214.pdf) - 22.2 String Queries - pp. 488

> The **`GL_VERSION`** and **`GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION`** strings are laid out as follows:
>
> > `<version number><space><vendor-specific information>`
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > The version number is either of the form **major number.minor number** or **major number.minor number.release number**, where the numbers all have one or more digits.

What this means is that in a compliant OpenGL ES implementation the version string will begin with `OpenGL ES` where as in OpenGL it will begin with a number (though I would not assume that "number" is limited to the characters [0-9] given the vague language used). You could theoretically use this information to distinguish between the two.

But you should not infer that because an implementation reports a certain version number that it actually implements the required feature set for compliance - this was a ***huge*** issue back in the days of OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: I don't handle context creation.

Comment: @tower120: Alright, I clarified a few things so that you should be able to use the version string for this purpose. It is important to note that you cannot reliably use the version string to tell the actual version (as funny as that sounds). The specifications are, however, strict enough to distinguish between GL and GL ES this way.